# make_move_iterator for data member and const: how make it failed?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

Here is example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

class Foo {
public:
  void combine(std::vector<std::vector<float>> &all_data) const {
    all_data.insert(all_data.end(), std::make_move_iterator(data_.begin()),
            std::make_move_iterator(data_.end()));
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::vector<float>> data_;
};
```

The problem is it compiles without any warning,
while `const` + `std::make_move_iterator(not_volatile_data_member)` should
failed from my opinion.

Why it is not compile time error and how can I prevent such errors in the future?

EDIT:

I want compilation error if data from data-member (`data_`) can not be moved and I get copy instead of move, while I explictly  tell to the compiler that I want move via `make_move_iterator`.

Comment: a move usually falls back to a copy when stuff cannot be moved.

Comment: ".....except that dereferencing converts the value returned by the underlying iterator into an rvalue. If this iterator is used as an input iterator, the effect is that the values are moved from, rather than copied from." (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) there is no reason this should fail

Comment: The iterator part is irrelavent. The same happens with `std::move` if used in a similar manner. `a=std::move(b)` will simply copy `b` if `b` is `const`.

Comment: according to your reasoning this should be an error as well `const int x = 42; std::move(x);` but it is totally fine

Comment: Also in general such things cannot be detected at compile time. For a type `T` it is possible to detect that `T` is a move-only type, but not possible to detect that `T` has both copy and move constructors but which behave differently. Same goes for copy- and move-assignment operators.

Comment: "The problem is it compiles...." you should say why you think this would be a problem or what you want to prevent. One can guess what you mean, but obvious it is not

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** want to do it, and just want to detect the issue for `const`s. It can be achieved by adding your own wrapper.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Iter>
decltype(auto) my_make_move_iterator(Iter&& it){
    static_assert(!std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*it)>>);
    return std::make_move_iterator(std::forward<Iter>(it));
}

class Foo {
public:
  void combine(std::vector<std::vector<float>> &all_data) const {
    all_data.insert(all_data.end(), my_make_move_iterator(data_.begin()),
            my_make_move_iterator(data_.end()));
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::vector<float>> data_;
};
```

However, I am strongly against doing so because it doesn't prevent many other common errors similar to this and also makes the code **much** more confusing for others who happen to read your code.